# Do something every 3 loops in django-templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I wanna make change in css class every 3 loops. In the first three I want to use the CSS class A, in the next three I want to use the CSS class B, in the next three I want to use the CSS class A again and so on.

can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% cycle "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" %}
```